# Road bike 1.5" Integrated tapered Headtube to a 1 1/4 tapered Fork compatibility

Tags: fork, headtube

Currently have a road bike running with *1.5" Integrated tapered Headtube* with a *1.5" tapered fork* was looking to upgrade to an Enve road fork with a *1 1/4 Tapered fork*. Was wondering what would be the solution to keep the bearings that im currently using to have it fit on a 1 1/4 tapered fork? Can it be done with just changing the crown race for the fork? If yes what would be the crown race to be fitted on the fork?

Thanks!

*the question is a little bit tricky to sentence, my bad.*

Comment: Are there actually different tapers between road and MTB? Did not know that!

Comment: I think most manufacturers switching from straight to tapered steerers didn't bother with 1.25", so they don't need separate inventory for building road bikes and mtbs. 1.5" lower can look odd on a steel frame with narrow tubing. Giant went one step weirder for their Overdrive 2 spec, which has 1.25" upper and 1.5" lower.

Answer (score 1):

If the new fork takes a crown race, you can buy a special crown race to adapt 1 1/4" to 1 1/2". [these also exist for 1 1/8"]. Search your favorite buy-everything website for some options. It's a cheap, easy way to do it.

HOWEVER if the ENVE fork has an integrated crown race (which you will have to check with the manufacturer or the vendor), the crown-race type of adaptor won't be suitable. It may be possible to buy a shim (or have one machined) for your frame to take the 1 1/4" bearing but this solution is less commonly seen.